# How to unit-test WCF UriTemplates?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, unit-testing, url

How do I write a unit test to test the UriTemplates (such as `[WebGet(Uritemlpate="{clientId}/returns")]` in my WCF services?

For example, in Global.asax I have:

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
{
     RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("clients", 
                new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ClientService)));
}
```

In the ClientService I have a `[WebGet(Uritemlpate="uri_1")]`:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public class ClientService 
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "uri_1")]
        public string GetCollection()
        {
            return "Method 1";
        }

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "uri_2")]
        public string GetCollections()
        {
            return "Method 2";
        }
    }
```

I want to have a test that Asserts the url `clients/uri_1` hits exactly method GetCollection of ClientService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Unit Test` the methods `GetCollection` and `GetCollections` by just calling them and checking the return is not null.

What you are actually want to do is an `Integration Test`. This requires the external dependency of a web server. Check out the difference between the types here
[What is Unit test, Integration Test, Smoke test, Regression Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520064/what-is-unit-test-integration-test-smoke-test-regression-test)

It is worth while having both. We run `Unit Tests` when we commit code automatically, it is them auto-deployed to a integrations. domain, the `Integration Tests` are then run against this.