# What is the best practice for testing Models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, model

How much or how little should one test models in rails? Since the framework is basically doing so much for you, I'm wondering if it's worth testing the generated activerecord methods to make sure they work or not.

Do you guys test them implicitly through the controllers?

In the Java world, if I used Hibernate, I had to write so much ORM mapping stuff that testing save/delete/find for each entity was VERY important - even if I just inherited these methods from a base class - because it was easily possible to get the mapping information wrong, or make a silly mistake. Deletes were important to test to make sure Hibernate would cascade properly.

But since you don't configure any of this stuff in rails at all... it's just so simple... is it worth testing, or do you just assume it works? Do you just limit yourself to maybe making sure associations work as expected?

What is the best practice? Any good testing examples? I found a page here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

But it didn't talk specifically about ActiveRecord. It focused more on controllers and other things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't try to test any methods introduced by active record and such. They are already tested by the rails team. And they already have written test cases.

but i would test all my methods and basically any custom code that i write in my models. First to test them as individual units i will use unit tests. And to make sure the whole thing works (models controllers..etc) you can use integration tests.

the railsguides would be a very good starting point for you. afterwards you can digg in to more interesting stuff. i would recommend you to take a look and rspec and cucumber.

- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info)
- [Rspec](http://rspec.info)

Some more stackoverflow questions (and answers) that would be helpful to you

- [Getting Started with RSpec - Looking for tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201385/getting-started-with-rspec-looking-for-tutorials)
- [What is Unit test, Integration Test, Smoke test, Regression Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520064/what-is-unit-test-integration-test-smoke-test-regression-test)

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with testing - I've probably written 10,000 tests in the last few years alone ;) I am just new to ruby and rails. A lot of places focus on doing stuff with the framework, but not so much on testing practices. I'll definitely keep on reading then. Maybe I'll find a good rails app I can download and just look at their tests.

Comment: why not look at rails it self ;)

Comment: Oh, it's not that I don't know how to test in general, I meant what is meaningful from what isn't. In the java world, testing your save/delete/find is actually very meaningful and valuable because bugs can result if you don't test it... but I am guessing in rails that it isn't. Also, testing controllers probably has nuances that are very different from Spring MVC - even though the concepts are the same. It's just learning the differences really. But before I got into controllers, I wanted to work with models first.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a good idea to test active record, it's already very extensively tested, so you would only waste your time there.

You should test whatever YOU write. Any model method that you code should be tested. That is, do not test whether the Active Record delete method works, but if your implementation of the process works (like if a user clicks delete and he has the item, it gets deleted). Test the behaviour, not the means of doing it.

Take a look at this very nice cast on testing controllers with rspec :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec

Your mentioned resource is probably the best as well :) If you are interested in rspec, you will find some very nice information here :

http://rspec.info/