# Need some advice on integration testing for a server application

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

i need some advice to properly set up integration testing for a C [server application](https://github.com/evilsocket/gibson) i wrote.
The main problem is that the [client library](https://github.com/evilsocket/libgibsonclient) is in a project of its own, so which is the best approach ?

Should i put the client library as a git submodule ( both client and server are under git ) in the 'tests' folder of the server and make tests link to it ? 
Should i implement a minimal static client ( with binary strings to send commands ) and use it ?

Since this is the first time i seriously need integration testing I'm a little bit doubtful about which one of those approaches is the best one.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great definition of an integration test can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520116/203371). It states:

> Integration test: Test the correct inter-operation of multiple
>   subsystems. There is whole spectrum there, from testing integration
>   between two classes, to testing integration with the production
>   environment.

Typically you would have integration tests for your client, and separate integration tests for your server. However, what you are referring to are client-server integration tests.

To write these sort of tests I'd recommend using automated acceptance tests.  Using a test framework such as [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) you can write tests which would test specific features and scenarios, which would interact with both the client and server.

There is a C++ cucumber framework called [cucumber-cpp](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp) which (I assume) you could use to test your C based applications. There is also a video (albeit a poor one!) of it being used [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3KGSbZrwJQ).

Answer (score -3):

In my humble opinion both the client and the server should have two seperate test-suits. And binary strings (is that even possible?) sounds like a bad idea. Try to make the testsuite readable and not with any "magick numbers".

I wouldn't use a submodule solution just because of a test-suite.

Comment: ok, you wrote what i shouldn't do ... but without the client submodule and without a minimal client, how should i make tests for the server ?

Comment: As I said, I would have a seperate test suite each program (the server and the client).

A test-suite should probably contain a minimal client for the server and vice versa, however, notice the word minimal. A test-suite client can be very dumb and have a programmed serie of commands to execute.

The point is that a client update should never break the server test-suite. Which is possible if you use the client and the server to test eachother.