# The reason of usage axios-mock-adapter

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm a beginner to test axios calls and started using axios-mock-adapter but I don't get why we use axios-mock-adapter.

```
mock.onPost('/api').reply(200, userData, headers);
```

In this code snippet, does the request really go to the server or is this just a simulation?

Because if I give wrong credentials, it responses with 200 status as I identify it on '**reply**' to return 200.

So if I identify the response status, what is the reason to use it?
If it doesn't really go to server, it seems like this is useless.

Maybe I miss something I don't know because I'm new but someone should put the light on this issue on my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answers to your questions

> In this code snippet, does the request really go to the server or is this just a simulation?

It is just a simulation. No request is made, just the "reply" is returned. This is called [mocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) and is hugely popular and useful for writing tests.

If you are new to different kinds of testing in general, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520116/1695393) is well worth reading.

> If it doesn't really go to server, it seems like this is useless.

If you want to test the system as a whole: i.e. your website + backend logic (like auth, data retrieval etc.) then yes, this is useless. But you would not use a *mock* for that.

Integration tests typically are executed against a running system, they are valuable, but very hard to maintain and are generally slower to execute. You have to take care of not just your tests, but even the data.

### When would you use a mock

Mocks are essential for *unit testing* your code. Mocks help isolate your front end code logic from the dynamic behavior. This makes it easier for you to *simulate* many scenarios without the overhead of maintaining data.

### Example Scenario

**Use Case**
In your application, you have to authenticate a user against a REST end point. It is expected that:

1. When user is logged in successfully, Logout button is shown in the header.
2. When users password has expired, a "change your password" screen is shown.
3. When user has entered wrong credentials, a warning is shown
4. When backend is not responding user is shown a screen to try again later

Without mocks, you need to ensure that you have the exact data configured in your authentication system. From experience I can tell you it is hard, especially #2 & #4.

But with mocks, you can just configure the *mock* to return the response you expect for each scenarios, in/before *each* `it()` block.

This is also easier to maintain as expectation (assert/expect statements) is set near the test data (mock.reply()).

Comment: This answer is gold :) I appreciated

Comment: @BurakULU glad to be of help :-)