# How to really test signal handling in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, signals

My code is simple:

```
def start():
    signal(SIGINT, lambda signal, frame: raise SystemExit())
    startTCPServer()
```

So I register my application with signal handling of `SIGINT`, then I start a start a TCP listener.

here are my questions:

1. How can I using python code to send a SIGINT signal?
2. How can I test whether if the application receives a signal of SIGINT, it will raise a SystemExit exception?
3. If I run `start()` in my test, it will block and how can I send a signal to it?

Comment: You'd not unit test the signal itself. You'd mock the `signal` call instead. Testing the actual signal is a *functional test*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, then how to functional test this bit?

Comment: Run your script as a subprocess with `subprocess.Popen()` perhaps and send that subprocess a signal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it worked. really exit. please write your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Okay, written that up with a few references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of, testing the signal *itself* is a functional or integration test, not a unit test. See [What's the difference between unit, functional, acceptance, and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test)

You can run your Python script as a subprocess with [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), then use the [`Popen.send_signal()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal) to send signals to that process, then test that the process has exited with [`Popen.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).

Answer (score 6):

> 1. How can I using python code to send a SIGINT signal?

You can use `os.kill`, which slightly misleadingly, can used to send any signal to any process by its ID. The process ID of the application/test can be found by `os.getpid()`, so you would have...

```
 pid = os.getpid()
 #  ... other code discussed later in the answer ...
 os.kill(pid, SIGINT)
```

> 2. How can I test whether if the application receives a signal of SIGINT, it will raise a SystemExit exception?

The usual way in a test you can check that some code raises SystemExit, is with `unittest.TestCase::assertRaises`...

```
import start

class TestStart(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_signal_handling(self):

        #  ... other code discussed later in the answer ...

        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
           start.start()
```

> 3. If I run start() in my test, it will block and how can I send a signal to it?

This is the trick: you can start another thread which then sends a signal back to the main thread which is blocking.

Putting it all together, assuming your production `start` function is in `start.py`:

```
from signal import (
    SIGINT,
    signal,
)
import socketserver

def startTCPServer():
    # Taken from https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example
    class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

def start():
    def raiseSystemExit(_, __):
        raise SystemExit

    signal(SIGINT, raiseSystemExit)
    startTCPServer()
```

Then your test code could be like the following, say in `test.py`

```
import os
from signal import (
    SIGINT,
)
import threading
import time
import unittest

import start


class TestStart(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_signal_handling(self):
        pid = os.getpid()

        def trigger_signal():
            # You could do something more robust, e.g. wait until port is listening
            time.sleep(1)
            os.kill(pid, SIGINT)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=trigger_signal)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            start.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and run using

```
python test.py
```

---

The above is the same technique as in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500820/1319998

Comment: Would it be effectively the same thing, if I inherited my class being tested, and called `os.kill(pid, SIGINT)` inside an overrided method? That way I can also guarantee I am testing behavior of a known point in code when the signal arrived.