# Are HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance and the sender object in an IHttpModule always the same thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, request-pipeline

In order to facilitate unit testing of components that reference the `HttpApplication`, we have a class that uses a lambda + proxy wrapper to direct the call to either a mocked `HttpApplication` or the real `HttpApplication` (via a proxy class), using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance`.

However, we have code in an `IHttpModule` that is added to our pipeline, and one of the parameters of the event being fired is the `Object sender`, which is cast to an `HttpApplication`. In order to mock this appropriately, I would like to use the proxy class that refers to `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance` rather than the sender parameter on the event. Based on my reading of the [request pipeline documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx), I'm not sure how the two would ever be different, but I'm not certain enough to throw that in production and see if it's true. :)

Are they always the same? If not, does anyone have a good suggestion on how to mock references to `HttpApplication` in an `IHttpModule` where we are explicitly passed the `HttpApplication` reference?

Comment: This actually sounds like an integration test (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test).The HttpApplication is passed to IHttpModule Init so passing HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance should do it. Alternatively you can achieve this without the proxy, using a mocking tool like Typemock (www.typemock.com), which is more straightforward and gives you better control over the flow of the test. Can you please share a code snippet?