# Laravel: Unit test Route::group with prefix

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm new to Laravel and am following along with the [Play by Play: Getting Started with Laravel 5 with Steven Maguire](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/play-by-play-laravel-5-getting-started/table-of-contents) video in Pluralsight. This is a clean install of the `lavarvel/laravel` box in Vagrant. Laravel is at version 5.4.15 and PHPUnit is at version 5.7.16.

However, I can't seem to get my route tests to not fail as I add groups and controllers.

Here's my `routes/web.php` file:

```
<?php
Route::get('products', ['as' => 'products', function(){
    return App\Product::all();
}]);
```

Here's my `tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
    public function testProductsList(){
        $this->get(route('products'))
            ->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

With just this basic setup, when I run my tests, I get this response: `Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertResponseOk()`

After reading around, I restructured the test to this:

```
public function testProductsList(){
    $response = $this->get(route('products'));
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```

This new structure succeeds, so I proceeded with the video and next we added a route group. Here's the route group in the `routes\web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::get('products', ['as' => 'products', function(){
        return App\Product::all();
    }]);
});
```

This also succeeds. The problems begin when I introduce `Route::resource` into the flow. The tests begin to fail. Here's the new `routes\web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'update']]);
});
```

Here's the `ProductController` class in this file `app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I used `php artisan make:controller ProductController` to create this controller. Here's the error that I now receive: `InvalidArgumentException: Route [products] not defined.`

I tried to change the adjusted `testProductsList()` method back to the original code and it still doesn't work.

Any insights into how I can get past these errors? I'd prefer to keep the original `testProductsList()` method code, however, if that's just not how it works anymore, then as long as I can get it working, I'm fine. Thanks in advance for your help and insight!

***EDIT***

Per the comment, I deleted and recreated the `ProductController` class using the command `php artisan make:controller ProductController --resource`. I've edited the above contents in the file `app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php` to reflect the change. However, the test is still failing. With Alex's answer, I've also changed the `testProductsList` method to this, but with no change:

```
public function testProductsList(){
    /*
    * I tried just `products` for the route 
    * and still receive the error.
    */
    $this->get(route('api.products'));
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: if you're going to use `Route::resource()` you nee to use `php artisan make:controller ProductController --resource`. There are several functions missing from your controller method that `Route::resource()` requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `php artisan route:list` to get the names of the routes
I suspect the name of the route is not `products` (perhaps its `products.index` or `api.products.index`), hence the error.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Update `$this->get(route('products'));` with the correct name of the route as displayed by the route list artisan command (e.g. `$this->get(route('products.index'));`)
2. Instead of using the `route` helper function, refer to the route directly like so: `$this->get('/api/products/index');`
3. Rename the routes with custom names like so:

   ```
   Route::resource('products', 'ProductController', 
       ['names' => ['index' => 'products.list', // etc...]]);
   ```

Then use `$this->get(route('products.list'));`

Comment: I wanted to keep from hard coding the route into the test, just in case the route changed in the future, so I tried options 1 & 3, and though neither of them worked with these lines in the test method `$this->get(route('products.list')); $this->assertResponseOk();` (I got the previous error about `assertResponseOk()` being undefined), I got it to work with the adjusted code I listed above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You missed `$this`:

```
public function testProductsList(){
    $this->get(route('products'));
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Btw, it is not a unittest. See [What's the difference between unit, functional, acceptance, and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the differences in testing!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Route::group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'as' => 'api.'], function(){
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController', ['only' => ['index', 'store',     'update']]);
});
```