# Unit test standard ViewModel binder in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class BraintreeCallbackApiModel
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "bt_signature")]
    public string Signature { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "bt_payload")]
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

The values are POSTed to controller as `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters. I want to unit test the binding behavior - that `bt_signature` field is properly mapped to `Signature`.

I would like to avoid using `TestServer` and `HttpClient` as it's not needed overhead in this case.

I looked at ModelBinder tests on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Test/ModelBinding/Binders) but couldn't get it to bind to my model class.

Comment: What did you expect from testing an already tested part? Did you ever faced a situation where the model binder has failed?

Comment: I wanted to test it so that I know if someone removed ModelBinder attribute, or made a typo in the name of the field.

Comment: Then write a test that checks the presence of the attribute and the name.

Comment: yes... I think I am going to do that... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @SirRufo said, the unit test, in this case, may only check that `ModelBinder` class is working well, that has been already tested by ASP.NET Core team.

If you want to have a test, that will be broken when someone changes `bt_signature` field name (either in the model class or in request parameters), then you need to write a feature test. And so you need to run your app using `TestServer` and do a real request (via `HttpClient` as an example).

Look into [What's the difference between unit, functional, acceptance, and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test) if interesting.

Comment: Of course, I don't intend to test if `ModelBinder` works fine ;) I wan't to make sure, the binding config for this model is correct. As I said in the question, I know I can do it with `TestServer`, but wanted to make it lighter with a unit test...