# Programmatically fire onmousemove event in javascript

Tags: javascript, qunit, js-test-driver

I'm writing a javascript library that does something on window.onmousemove event, now I'm writing the unit test for this code. How do I fire onmousemove for window object manually? For eg. I fire an event `somethingHappened` when `window.onmousemove` and other events are triggered, I want the unit test to make sure that the `somethingHappened` is triggered on onmousemove.

I'm using jsTestDriver with qUnit for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the `onmousemove()` handler:

```
​window.onmousemove = function(){console.log('called');}​​​​​;
window.onmousemove();​
```

PS

Anyway what you're trying to perform [is an integration test, not a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437897/what-are-unit-testing-and-integration-testing-and-what-other-types-of-testing-s)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call `window.onmousemove()` anywhere you want?

```
if(condition) {
   window.onmousemove();
}
```